# Using MySQL database twice in the same function returns a 1 instead of actual string

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am struggling to understand why I am getting a 1 returned after the second time I use my database in my function. I need to access two different tables to get the information I need.

```
class getSubdivs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'shannon')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def openConnection(self):
        self.con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'shannon')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def closeConnection(self):
        self.con.commit()
        self.cur.close()

    def getAllSubdivsforTable(self):
        self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM SUBDIVS')
        info = self.cur.fetchall()
        print info
            dict = {}  #dictionary object that creates the RR collection of the RR resources 
        for x in info:
            littleDict = {} #makes a little dictionary object that will fill the other dictionary object
            ID = x[0]
            name = x[3]
            que = ('SELECT RailroadName FROM RAILROADS WHERE SCAC = %s')
            company = self.cur.execute(que, ID)
            print 'This is the company'
            print company
            book['name'] = name
            book['company'] = company
            book['link'] = None #place holder for now, will be used later

        data = json.dumps(book)
        return data
```

Is there a way I can clear the cursor that is in mySQL to make it so that I can get information from a second table?

My code returns this
    This is the company
    1
    {"company": 1, "link": null, "name": "TINY TRUCK RAILS"}

Even though the database has "Railroad Company" stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a second cursor instead of reusing it?

Edit, you're not calling fetchall on the second query!!

Comment: I changed the middle part of the code to this and now it works perfectly! Thanks

que = ('SELECT RailroadName FROM RAILROADS WHERE SCAC = %s')
            self.cur.execute(que, ID)
            company = self.cur.fetchall()[0][0]
            print 'This is the company'
            print company

Comment: Awesome!! Well if you feel i helped out, then don't forget to accept the answer :) good luck!